# program comunication and file permission (server side)

Tags: c#, php, security, file-io

I've made a little program to manage xml file on a web.
This program send data to PHP file(on a server) and PHP modify content to xml.
Now all work's if permission to PHP and XML are 777.
Program send data via

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
```

My question is How to secure file,and allow acces to PHP only to my program,and how allow only PHP to write XML file.

Comment: Who is the owner of the _file_ and what user is running apache?

Comment: owner is running,apache2 server.

Comment: What about securing your PHP script with [`basic authentication`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) and making your client program ask for credentials everytime it needs to call the script?

Comment: simple autentication via code check.is only for test,i need understand security.

Comment: If you need to understand security, then you need to understand that the only way to make the 2 applications work together in a trusted way is to make them agree on a commonly shared secret. Username/password is what is being used quite often on the world wide web today.

Comment: ok,but i need understanding how to grant acces to PHP and XML same i've exposed in my question.

Comment: You mean like only the PHP script could modify the XML file? What about the administrators of the server on which this PHP script runs? Are they supposed to be able to modify it as well or not?

Comment: if i set XML to 777,PHP modify it,otherwise no.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. So let me repeat it once again: `is a user having administrative account on your web server supposed to be able to modify the XML file or not?`

Comment: ops,sorry..user of PHP file have permission granted.